# Git checkout: "@{-N}" syntax

Tags: git

I found this section in the git manpage, but it's kind of an obfuscated explaination:

> As a special case, the "@{-N}" syntax for the N-th last branch
>   checks out the branch (instead of detaching). You may also specify
>   - which is synonymous with "@{-1}".

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's saying that if you do:

```
git checkout @{-1}
```

You'll check out the branch you were on before the current branch you have checked out.  In addition, it checks it out *by name*, so you'll actually be *on* that branch, rather than just checking out that commit in a detached HEAD state.  Similarly, you could use `git checkout @{-2}` to go back "two branch changes ago", and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

That somewhat "obfuscated" explanation is clarified with Git 2.16 (Q1 2018).
`@{-N}` in "`git checkout @{-N}`" may refer to a detached HEAD state,
but the documentation was not clear about it, which has been fixed.

See [commit 75ce149](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75ce14957507bc310ad118df08c4a85fd9cedc0d) (27 Nov 2017) by [Kaartic Sivaraam (`sivaraam`)](https://github.com/sivaraam).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7065665](https://github.com/git/git/commit/706566524ef59a97e89ba895b800398ef823d109), 13 Dec 2017)</sup>

> `Doc/checkout`: checking out using `@{-N}` can lead to detached state
>
> `@{-N}` is a syntax for the **N-th last "checkout"** and not just the N-th last "branch". Therefore, in some cases using `git checkout @{-$N}`
>   DOES lead to a "detached HEAD" state.
>   This can also be ensured by the commit message of [75d6e55](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75d6e552a8f289fb0ee606a7bdfceace6df93bb3) (Documentation: `@{-N}` can refer to a commit, 2014-01-19, Git 1.9-rc1) which clearly specifies how `@{-N}` can be used to refer not only to a branch but also to a commit.
>
> Correct the misleading sentence which states that `@{-N}` doesn't detach HEAD.

The [`git checkout` man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/75ce14957507bc310ad118df08c4a85fd9cedc0d/Documentation/git-checkout.txt#L266-L268) now reads:

> You can use the `"@{-N}"` syntax to refer to the N-th last
>   branch/commit checked out using "git checkout" operation.
>   You may also specify `-` which is synonymous to `"@{-1}`.