# git checkout PREV

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-reflog

Is there a simple way to switch back to the branch you were most recently on prior to the current one? The same concept as "cd -" from the command line.

When working on multiple branches, this can be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
git checkout -
```

Note the dash.
This checks out the latest branch you were on before the current one.

As you can see, the syntax is analogous to `cd -`

Comment: Wow, I didn't give the git dev team enough credit. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice trick. After you mentioned it, I found it buried in the [git-checkout(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) man page. I've posted the quote from the man page as another answer, so it can be formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I never would have found this without the answer from @KlasMellbourn, but this is actually mentioned in the [git-checkout(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) man page (in the portion describing `<branch>`):

```
As a special case, the "@{-N}" syntax for the N-th last branch checks out the
branch (instead of detaching). You may also specify - which is synonymous with
"@{-1}".
```

Comment: Note (4,5 years later) That part of the doc has just slightly changed: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47839400/6309

Comment: If you have edit access, feel free to update the post.